# What is the radius of the next convergence

Tags: calculus

What is the radius of convergence of:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(1-x)^{5n}}{n5^n\ln(n)}$$

I know that I should use power series but how?

Comment: This question was asked yesterday, although not fully answered. I'll repeat what I suggested there: try either the ratio or root test. Either of those will give you the radius of convergence.

Comment: The factor $n\log n$ grows too slow to influence the convergence in any way. If you prove it and replace that factor with $1$, you get a series that is easy to compute in closed-form.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Technically it is relevant at the boundary of the region of convergence, i.e. where $\frac{|1-x|^5}{5}=1$. For instance the situation changes at one of those points if I replace the factor of $n$ with $n^2$.

Comment: @Ian: yes, you are right, but clearly the radius of convergence stays the same.

Comment: I don't understand how can I get series do look like: sum An*x^n

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-x)^5n}{n 5^n \ln(n)}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)} \left( \frac{(1-x)^5}{5} \right)^n
$$
and the exponent will dominate the $n \ln(n)$ in the denominator, which suggests using root test or ratio test to get you where you want to be,.